# How can I copy a Delaunay triangulation to new points?

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I am currently using the Delaunay function in scipy.spatial.Delaunay, like so (simplified):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

points1 = np.random.rand(10,2)
points2 = np.random.rand(10,2)

tri = Delaunay(points1)
# tri2 = tri(points2)? - need help here
```

I would like to have the same triangulation applied to point2 - if I run Delaunay again I might get a different triangulation.

Is it possible to 'copy' one triangulation and apply it to a different set of points of the same size?

Comment: You’re okay with the result having overlapping triangles if the points are too different?

Comment: @DavisHerring yes- my points are facial landmarks,  so there shouldn't be much difference

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the hybrid triangulation such that it matters?  You can already use `d.simplices` and `d.neighbors` with whatever point array you want.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm trying to create a consistent triangle 'face mask'-  so that if a person is smiling or frowning the triangulation won't change-  could you explain how to use the simplicies and the neighbors properties to achieve that? I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: The `Delaunay` object, in its most basic usage (those two attributes), defines the _topology_ of a triangulation whose _geometry_ you already had (and provided as input).  Whatever you want to do with the triangulation (_e.g._, render it) can be done by using that topology in conjunction with whatever geometry you like--the original is the obvious choice, but it makes no difference to use another of the same cardinality (so long as it's not "too different").

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you!  could you provide code on how to change said geometry?  also-  I'm using the function `find_simplex` to figure out which pixel goes into which triangle-  will changing the geometry also update the `find_simplex` response correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173277/discussion-between-davis-herring-and-shtut).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness' sake,   based on [Davis Herring's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8586227/davis-herring) response in the comments-

`tri.simplices` contains the relation between the indices of the input,  and doesn't rely on the actual values.

if for example I got a triangle between `points[0]`, `points[3]` and `points[4]`, `tri.simplices` will contain `[0,3,4]`.

so to access the same triangulation with different 'points'  I can just access them like so:

```
points2[tri.simplices]
```